# Sourcing static maps from web APIs

Tags: openstreetmap, google-maps, web-mapping, map-service, static

For a web app I want to source roadmap and satellite type maps from a web API which will be used with geometrical data from a database to generate reports. The reports would be viewed on screen or printed out.  Print would require 300 dpi resolution to avoid blurring. Width/height approximately 17cm would be ideal.

Sources of map data may be Google Maps, MapBox, OpenStreetMap or another. OpenStreetMap has fair usage policies and their servers aren't designed for commercial use.

I would like to find out what Server Side Rendering options exist.

Answer (score 1):

[Nik4](https://github.com/Zverik/Nik4) may be a good solution for you. It is based on the [Mapnik](https://mapnik.org/) library and renders OSM data. You can define size of the output image as well as print resolution.

Also I used [node-mapnik](https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik) together with [Mapnik](https://mapnik.org/) to render custom maps for PDF reports.